# How can I mount the secondary partition(/dev/sda2) as read-only mode in ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I have three partition(/dev/sda1, sda2 and sda3). The first partition /dev/sda1 is default ubuntu and mounted as root("/"), remaining two partition not any mount points. If I want then go to mount the partitions.

I want to install ubuntu in /dev/sda2 partition. manually I unsquashfs the filesystem and copied kernel and initrd from iso image. After that I adding the menu entries in grub configuration file. finally that booted fine but it was mount read-write mode. I want to write read-only(ro) mode. how to mounted read only or where to mention read-only flag. please any one have answer let me know.

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you installing? From your question < If I want then go to mount the partitions.> What does this mean? Lastly why are you trying to do what ever it is you are trying to do?

Comment: Have you tried adding 'ro' param to your kernel command line?

Comment: I am taking ubuntu 20.04 version from community.

Answer (score 1):

The way a partition is mounted can be specified through the mount options. To mount the file system read only, the option you add simply is `ro`, either on the command line, or, if the partition is automatically mounted during startup, in the configuration file `/etc/fstab`.

See `man mount` for possible mount options for different file systems. For ntfs file systems, this information is available in `man mount.ntfs`.

Comment: Yes I hands-on with your idea I faced the error during the booting. If you are mount the partition (/dev/sda2) read-only, then faced the some service not started during the booting. I think may be read-write rights required for booting.

Comment: Your question is how to mount a partition read only. If yo have another issue, feel free to open a question for it. It this answers the question, then please accept the answer.